# How to use a Toolbar Button without redirect?

Tags: component, administrator, redirect

I am developing a Joomla Administrator Component. In the Toolbar, I created a Button via

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('administrat.saveIt', 'save.png', 'save.png', 'SOME_TEXT', false);
```

In my controller, the function `saveIt` does not contain any Redirect statement. Still, when I klick the button it redirects me to an empty page, which i do not want.

What can i do, to Prevent this Button from redirecting?

Comment: Have you tried setting a redirect to the **current** page?

Comment: Yes, but still it reloads the page then. I dont want anything to happen with the page when i press this button.

Comment: If you don't want anything to happen, you'll need to use Javascript for this then

Comment: You mean overriding the JToolbarHelper-Button? Or creating an own button?